# Feynman-Kac statement with no boundedness condition

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-differential-equations

Theorem 5.3 of Friedman (1975, Volume I) and its version in Theorem 7.6 of Karatzas & Shreve (1991) both establish conditions under which the Feynman-Kac formula holds, namely there is a probabilistic solution to a Cauchy problem over $[0,T)\times\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align}
& \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+\mathscr{A}_tv-kv+g=0\\
& v(T,x)=f(x)
\end{align}
where $v:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is assumed continuous, differentiable and satisfying a polynomial growth condition (equation (7.14) in Karatzas & Shreve), with the operator $\mathscr{A}_t$ defined as (equation (4.1) in Karatzas & Shreve):
\begin{align}
(\mathscr{A}_tf)(t,x):=
\frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,x)^2\frac{\partial^2f(t,x)}{\partial x^2}
+b(t,x)\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial x}
\end{align}
then $a:=\sigma^2$ and $b$ are required to be bounded, see condition (ii) in Remark 7.8 from Karatzas and Shreve or condition (B1) in Section 5 of Friedman.

This is very inconvenient: if we view the operator $\mathscr{A}_t$ as the generator of a geometric Brownian motion, this effectively precludes applying the Feynman-Kac formula to that particular case because $a(t,x)=\sigma^2x$ which is unbounded for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Karatzas & Shreve mention in Remark 7.8 that the theorem conditions can be made local and refer to page 147 of Friedman, but the latter reference only seems to relax continuity requirements - not boundedness ones.

On the other hand, the advantage of those formulations with respect to other ones I have seen, for example in the book from Öksendal on SDEs, is that the functions $f$ and $g$ are required to be continuous only - and not differentiable. This is quite handy when considering specifications of $f$ and $g$ which might include the minimum or maximum operator.

**Is there a reference with a statement of the Feynman-Kac theorem which does not include the boundedness requirement while preserving continuity-only for $f$ and $g$?**

**More generally, is there a good reference for more general statements of the Feynman-Kac theorem?** I have the impression this is one mathematical result for which there is a panoply of versions, each one with different conditions.